# How to display text and icon on the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am tryin to display a text with an icon on the action bar. i wrote the below code:

```
<item
 android:id=...
 android:title="title"
 android:icon="@drawable/fra"
 android:showAsAction="withtext"/>
```

but the result is a clickable action bar with nothing displayed

Comment: are your emphasis to use actionBar? because work with toolbar in your case is better.

Comment: @Ashkan ca u please tell me why it would be better to work with toolBar? and would u please provide an example

Comment: toolbar is the new version of ActionBar simply. in toolbar you can set your icon, text, image simpler.

Comment: see this link for toolbar demo http://techlovejump.com/android-toolbar-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

You may add  `app:showAsAction="always"`

```
  <item
        ...

        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: I think you can only show icon or text. if you want to show text remove icon. or if you want custom implementation see @Udi I answer

Answer (score 2):

You can also use code to achieve ActionBar custom display, for example:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_title);
```

And a layout in which you define what you need, that's just an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/some_image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u please tell me in which life cycle callback i should use ur code?is it onStart()

Comment: You should use it in onCreate

Comment: so you code doesnt need to onCreateOptionMenu?does it?

Answer (score 0):

this is the sample of toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```